# Ksoap Blackberry PropertyInfo.setValue

Tags: blackberry, ksoap, propertyinfo

so i im using the PropertyInfo to pass complex objects in my soap request, and its working fine on android, sample :

```
        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.name = "envelope";
        pi.setName("envelope");
        pi.setValue(envelope);
        pi.setType(envelope.getClass().toString());
```

//envelope is a KvmSerializable class with namespace mappings.

now im trying to do the same for blackberry, but its not liking the "setName" or "setValue" parameters.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
soapObject.addProperty("envelope", envelope);
```

from [SoapObject#addProperty](http://ksoap.objectweb.org/software/documentation/api/org/ksoap/SoapObject.html#addProperty%28org.kobjects.serialization.PropertyInfo,%20java.lang.Object%29)